# Sum of Money(datatype) in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to get the sum of a column of `money` datatype in SQL Server 2005?

I get an error

> Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.

when I use

```
sum(AmountSold) as Amount
```

Thanks in advance!

Complete query is like this: Not adding group by here because it has over 15 columns listed.

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(RepDailyCollection.CommunityID)             AS DaysinTown,
       SUM(CAST(RepDailyCollection.AmountSold AS MONEY)) AS TownValue,
       SUM(RepDailyCollection.Spots)                     AS Spots,
       SUM(RepDailyCollection.AmountCollected)           AS Collected,
       CommuniTee.StartDate                              AS StartDate,
       Community.EndDate                                 AS EndDate,
       Community.IsClosed                                AS TownStatus
FROM   Community
       INNER JOIN RepDailyCollection
         ON RepDailyCollection.CommunityID = Community.CommunityID
WHERE  Community.RepID = @RepID
```

Also, editing with Create table query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RepDailyCollection](
[RepDailyCollectionID] [bigint] IDENTITY(7500,1) NOT NULL,
[RepDailyInfoID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[CommuniTeeID] [int] NULL,
[AmountSold] [money] NULL,
[AmountCollected] [money] NULL,
[Spots] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
[IsCleared] [bit] NOT NULL,
[PaymentMethod] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
[CheckNumber] [bigint] NULL,
[Invoice] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
[TypeofCreditCard] [nvarchar](30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
[OrderID] [int] NULL,
[NewCompanyName] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
[PaymentDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: So `AmountSold` must be of `nvarchar` datatype not `money` then.

Comment: The answer is in the error message

Comment: What is the output of `exec sp_help 'RepDailyCollection'`? You are also summing 2 other columns that might cause this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `nvarchar` as your datatype you can't use the aggregate function `SUM()`.  The error states that the datatype of your `AmountSold` column is `nvarchar`, not `money`.

If your `AmountSold` column does create numeric data in the form of `nvarchar`, you can do this:

```
sum(cast(AmountSold as money))
```

**EDIT**: After looking at your `CREATE TABLE` command, your problem is that `Spots` is of `nvarchar` datatype and you're trying to call `sum()` on `Spots`.  That is why you're getting the error.

If `Spots` does create numeric data, then you need to do:

```
sum(cast(Spots as int))
```

Comment: if contains digits can be cast to money ... is not?

Comment: @Shark I have the datatype of AmountSold as money.

Comment: @Ram: No, you don't - otherwise you wouldn't be getting this error message.... I suggest you check again - that column is definitely **NOT** of type `money` (or the error actually concerns some other `SUM` operation in your query somewhere.....)

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for letting me understand but I have checked this few times, I am Sorry, its money :-(

Comment: I have only 2 rows in my table and has values 500.00 and 1000.00 in the column AmountSold. Does this help you guys in any way?

Comment: @Ram - Please post your entire query into the question.

Comment: @Ram Either the `sum()` command you put in your question has a typo or is just a wrong copy, or `AmountSold` is not `money`.  It's a very cut and dry error.

Comment: @Ram just because they have `500.00` and `1000.00` as their data doesn't mean their money.  The *data type* is defined in the table definition.  Script your table as a `CREATE` and post it in your question.

Comment: @Shark That is how i checked the datatype :-). I have given values to make sure '.' has nothing to do with the error :-)

Comment: @Shark, AmountCollected is again the same money datatype and Spots is int. I am sorry!

Comment: @Ram `sum()` wouldn't choke on `int`.  You are calling `sum()` on an `nvarchar` field.

Comment: @Ram I see that `Spots` is `nvarchar`.  That's the source or your error.

Comment: That is the source! Haaah. Is that the reason?!

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time! I am very sorry!! And Thanks a lot. I changed datatype of spot but i din't double check. :-(

Comment: @Ram No problem at all.  Glad to help. :)